# Using START in a cmd file starting more than 2K processes

Tags: windows, batch-file

I tried to wrap a little command in a batchfile to prevent me from typing it the whole time. But the result was a mess! I'm ended up with thousands of cmd processes and was unable to stop it with `CTRL+C`

The command was quite simple `START iisreset`

System Win7 64bit

Why is that happening?

EDIT:

With some help and additional tests I can now say that the Batch command `START` within a *.cmd file cause that mess. It opens a new commandwindow with every window until it crashes. Maybe you have luck and hit `CTRL-C` exactly the right time, but that really has to be luck. Anyway I will not use this command in future and it also seems not to be applicable to all machines. *(Read the comments for full history of this)*

Comment: What was the bat file called?

Comment: And the entire bat file was "`START iisreset`"? Nothing else?  What output did you get in the command window that you ran it from?

Comment: @forsvarir Nothing else. And it doesn't matter if you have a iis installed, I think any other name will also crash. You can try it yourself without any harm I think (I already had a little fun with some of my colleagues). You can initiate a logoff using `CTRL+ALT+DEL` to stop it

Comment: I don't have this problem at all... I'd guess it's localised to your system... what happens when you type `START` on it's own in a command window?

Comment: It starts another commandwindow. It cannot be localized to my system cause it happens also by all of my colleagues (tricked six so far) so windows7 64bit Enterprise & Ultimate are affected...

Comment: I suppose `res.cmd` is called by `iisreset`

Comment: So, running `IISRESET` on it's own on the command line works?  And, running `START iisreset` on it's own on the command line works?  But putting it in `res.cmd` creates a bunch of command processes?  Works fine on Windows 7, 64bit, Pro...  It could still be localised (assuming all of your colleagues are on say a company network with similar paths setup etc)... or you may have found a bug... are you running an up to date / patched version of the OS?

Comment: @jeb No. iisreset resets the IIS... @forsvarir First: all systems are updated. We are all in one network, but they are in the domain an I am not, so there are already difference. And the command runs local. It also happens if the PC is not connected to the network.

Comment: @sra: and... running `IISRESET` on it's own on at the command prompt works? And, running `START iisreset` on it's own on the command prompt works?

Comment: @forsvarir  Sorry, I forgot that: YES and YES. The second start the command in a new window.

Comment: @sra: Looks like it *might* be a bug...You could try raising a bug report  (although that seems like a non-trivial exercise) http://superuser.com/questions/67131/how-do-you-file-a-bug-report-for-windows

Comment: @forsvarir thanks for the link, but it seems a bit complicated to submit a bug therefore I just live with it. Post your last comment as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @sra: you never know... it might go away in a future update :)

Comment: You could try to change the name of `res.cmd` to `xyz.cmd` and add logging like `echo start %time% >> log.txt & start iisreset & echo end %time%`

Comment: @jeb the name of the file doesn't matter, I already changed it. It seems that the command `START` in a cmd file started from the desktop get stuck in a loop while always open a new command windows with every new window. But thanks anyways

Comment: @sra I´m one of the colleagues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works OK on Windows 7 pro, 64 bit, but based on the other stuff you've tried, it looks like it *might* be a bug... You could try raising a bug report
[(although that seems like a non-trivial exercise)](https://superuser.com/questions/67131/how-do-you-file-a-bug-report-for-windows).